# I want to include my style.css in function.php file?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, css

I'm new to WordPress. I'm including my file using

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="<?php bloginfo("stylesheet_url")?>"/>
```

But if i enqueue my css file in `functions.php` it is not working. Why?
Where is my mistake?

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style('style',get_template_directory_uri())?>
```

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the function wrong. You have not given your filename, just a directory.

From the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

```
wp_enqueue_style( string $handle, string $src = false, array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, string $media = 'all' )
```

so in your case, you should enqueue like so

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_my_style' );
function wpse_my_style(){
  wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'path/to/your/css' );
}
```

the rest of the parameters are optional

Answer (score -1):

```
function wpdocs_style() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );  //This is for getting style.css of current theme
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name1', get_teplate_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css', array('jquery') );   //This is for getting other css file from parent directory  
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name1', get_teplate_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery') );   //This is for getting JS file from parent directory  
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_style' );
             OR
//Or as an laternate you can hook with wp_head also
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpdocs_style' );
```

In order to run the above function need to add `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>` (If you use this action `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_style' );`) in `header.php` befor `</head>`.

You have to assign name to every style (like I assign style-name, style-name1 etc) and name should be unique.
And if you want to qnqueue from child theme's functions.php then you have to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_teplate_directory_uri()`.

Comment: OP question does not mention jquery at all. And you should NOT just add it in to header.php you should enqueue it like the styles.

Comment: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will work for theme AND child theme

Comment: @Nath I know he didn't mentioned jquery! so what, if I wanna provide some additional info that will help him and as well as future viewers also.

Comment: Okay you need to explain it better then. And also give correct information.

Comment: @Nath I have shown correct way. I am not getting whats wrong in my code! This is how I use to do and it works fine in my case. Dont know why you are mentioning its not correct! You said it should not be add in header.php! IF now there then where? If you have any better way then post an answer, I will also love to know any better way of it.

Comment: @Rishabh You hook jQuey exactly the same way you hook everything else. That is with `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.  You said that in order to run your code, we need to add jQuery in header.php before `</head>` why are you saying that? it's just not true. Especially not true when adding CSS files. So if you want to provide more information to help him and others that will read this answer, please do so in a way that is not confusing people. In no way CSS requires jQuery in order to _run_.  With `wp_enqueue_script` you have a parameter that tells WP to load in `<head>` or before closing `</body>`

Comment: So  instead of adding script all over the place making it more difficult to debug and read your code, you can add all scripts in the same place and use the `$deps` parameter which tells WP in which sequence to load the scripts/CSS in order to respect your dependencies.

Comment: @bynicolas Ok got your point. But in my updated answer I have shown an alternate way of hook with `wp_head` and in discription I told to add `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>` but also I mentioned only if you won't use hook with `wp_head`. So my second way in which I  have shown hook to add with `wp_head` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`, is it fine according to you?

Comment: Even though it works, I wouldn't recommend that as a standard practice, it's better to group all your script/CSS together, makes it easier for your (the dev) and other to read and understand your code.